# jquery template to find the length of data result

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

We are using Jquery template , and i need to print the button **Click Here** only if the result data is > 1

I tried below thing but it is not working.

```
<script id="xyz" class="sectionTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
{{if data.length > 1}}
        <button type="button" class="button_secondary editButton">Click Here</button>
{{/if}}
</script>
```

data passed to this template is `List<UserData>` by setting into data variable

Please suggest me any idea how can i find the length of data inside jquery template.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: make sure data object passed to template .tmpl() function is named 'data' i.e. $("#xyx").tmpl(data);

Comment: yes that is correct....no issue with that, in fact if i try if condition like {{if data.length}} , it goes inside if , only thing is i dont know why length is not coming

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/newuserjs/hfkamb2v/1/ i setup test data with template. seems to work fine here.